# Fukushima vs Thorium

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

This is **not** a question about traditional nuclear power plants vs the thorium based. But about the Fukushima plant itself and the very negative environmental effects from its meltdown of reactors 1 and 3 vs a Thorium based design under similar natural stressors.

[Fukushima leaking radioactive water for ‘2 years, 300 tons flowing into Pacific daily’](http://rt.com/news/japan-fukushima-nuclear-disaster-164/)

This is the basic outline of what happened to cause the melt down.

> Immediately after the earthquake, the remaining reactors 1–3 shut down
>   automatically and emergency generators came online to power
>   electronics and coolant systems. However, the tsunami following the
>   earthquake quickly flooded the low-lying rooms in which the emergency
>   generators were housed. The flooded generators failed, cutting power
>   to the critical pumps that must continuously circulate coolant water
>   through a Generation II reactor for several days to keep it from
>   melting down after shut down. After the pumps stopped, the reactors
>   overheated due to the normal high radioactive decay heat produced in
>   the first few days after nuclear reactor shutdown (smaller amounts of
>   this heat normally continue to be released for years, but are not
>   enough to cause fuel melting).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukushima_Daiichi_nuclear_disaster

I am just wondering if this was a Thorium reactor, would all of this had taken place in the first place? Because thorium needs to be constantly primed and not cooled.

I am not an engineer nor a paid scientist so please excuse my ignorance. I am just very curious.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a meaningful question: there is no one "thorium reactor" design. There's just a thorium-uranium fuel cycle. And essentially, this is an engineering question.

Comment: I disagree. Maybe i did not make myself clear. The plant itself is an engineering question but i am asking under the stresses experienced in Japan during the event, would the nuclear reaction process that lead to the meltdown have occurred if the said plant was using a thorium based process for the creation of energy. If it is only the design of the plant that makes a difference then you are right.

Comment: Did you re-post this on Engineering.StackExchange?

Answer (score 5):

This is not so much a question of nuclear fuel (uranium fuel cycle versus thorium fuel cycle) as the question of reactor design such as choice of liquid vs solid nuclear fuel, choice of coolant / moderator containment vessel design.

For instance molten salt reactors have *freeze plug*  safety feature allowing evacuation of nuclear fuel in passively safe storage in case of overheating. But one can have molten salt reactors on thorium fuel cycle such as [LFTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_fluoride_thorium_reactor), on the other hand it is also possible with molten uranium chloride based reactors. Also eliminating water as coolant can be done with uranium and thorium fuels.

One could also conceive thorium fuel cycle reactor designs equally prone to the type of accidents as Fukushima.

Comment: "... prone to the type of accidents as Fukushima." How so? There is no electrical system in the cooling process. This was the weak point in the event that lead to disaster. Thorium also works at atmospheric pressure which negates a hydrogen explosion event.

Comment: Nuclear fuel does not need to operate at specific pressure. With thorium cycle one could build solid state breeding blanket and use ceramic pellets clad in zirconium rods for fissile material reusing most of uranium cycle design and technology. It also provides with the same potential for decay heat to cause boiling  of water / hydrogen explosion in case of cooling systems accidents.

Comment: Additionally, look at the [section in wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorium_reactor#List_of_thorium-fueled_reactors). The majority of them uses solid state fuels (ThO$_2$). The list also has boiling water reactors -- the same type as Fukushima Daiichi.

Comment: I guess this is more an engineering question .. sorry for the inconvenience